# Why are my variables not reset to zero?

Tags: bash, shell-script

In the below loop, I try to reset the values of two variables (totalentries and totalusedbytes) to zero, but I can see from the results that it never happens. Thus each loop continues to add to the previous loops running totals

```
# For each grid name, get a list of map indexes for that gridname
for grid in "${gridNames[@]}"
   do
      totalentries=0
      totalusedbytes=0
      indexlist=`snmpwalk -v 2c -c splunk $host mapGridName -m $APPLIANCEMIB -OUQs -Ln | grep $grid | sed -n 's/.*mapGridName\.\([0-9]\+\)[^0-9].*/\1/p'`
      # Split list into an array
      while read -r line; do
          indexes+=(`echo $line`)
      done <<< "$indexlist"

      # Get the stats
      for index in "${indexes[@]}"
      do
         # Entries in Cache
         numentries=`snmpget -v 2c -c splunk $host mapNumEntries.$index -m $APPLIANCEMIB -OUQs -Ln | sed -n 's/.*\=[^0-9]\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/p'`
         # Used Bytes
         usedbytes=`snmpget -v 2c -c splunk $host mapUsedBytes.$index -m $APPLIANCEMIB -OUQs -Ln | sed -n 's/.*\=[^0-9]\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/p'`
         if [[ $numentries ]]
         then
             totalentries=`expr $totalentries + $numentries`
         fi
         if [[ $usedbytes ]]
         then
             totalusedbytes=`expr $totalusedbytes + $usedbytes`
         fi
      done
      echo $grid"_totalentries="$totalentries
      echo $grid"_totalusedbytes="$totalusedbytes
   done
```

Here is the output, most of the grids in the loop have nothing yet they get the previous loop's sum

```
A_grid_totalentries=0
A_grid_totalusedbytes=0
B_grid_totalentries=3
B_grid_totalusedbytes=30142
C_totalentries=3
C_totalusedbytes=30142
D_grid_totalentries=3
D_grid_totalusedbytes=30142
E_grid_totalentries=3
E_grid_totalusedbytes=30142
F_totalentries=3
F_totalusedbytes=30142
G_grid_totalentries=92
G_grid_totalusedbytes=1054348
H_grid_totalentries=96
H_grid_totalusedbytes=1114431
I_grid_totalentries=96
I_grid_totalusedbytes=1114431
```

Comment: You are dead right - told you it was a brain fart! added 'unset indexes' to end of loop and all is fine :) Please copy paste into an answer so I can give you credit :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you keep adding to the indexes array, and never reset that. While you reset those variables to zero, set the array to be empty:

```
  totalentries=0
  totalusedbytes=0
  indexes=()
```

Or, populate the array in a different way:

```
  mapfile -t indexes <<< "$indexlist"
```